# Is it possible to eat an object affected by Allfood while in combat? If so, how is the damage handled?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, food-and-drink

I realize this is a very strange and seemingly useless question, but hear me out on this. I've recently been assessing more creative uses of spells that seem useless in combat but may be made useful under the right conditions. I ran into the spell [*allfood*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/allfood/). It's a rather useful spell that can turn anything into a consumable food so long as it falls within the weight parameters of the spell: 5 lbs. per caster level. Of course, the limitations on this spell are *huge* in that an attended item gets a Will save to negate the effect and SR must be overcome.

The way I see it, it should be possible for a character to disarm their opponents, steal their weapons, and make those weapons into food to be eaten. But there's the devil in the details, specifically for the act of eating. Eating food seems to be an out-of-combat task that's to be done during rests, so no rules seem to cover how long eating takes or if it's even feasible to do so in combat.

The first question: What action should it be?  According to the rules, it seems like a standard action would be necessary to hold a weapon and bite into it, much like how you hold an enemy and attack it in a grapple, only the object (usually) won't fight back in this case.  However, it could be argued that it should be a full-round action. Obviously, despite whatever action it may take, the action should provoke attacks of opportunity.

And that's about the only simple part of this whole ordeal that I can reason out, and even that's not decisive. The rest of the details seem to be very difficult to find information on if any info exists. These details are as follows:

- How much damage does eating deal to the object? As the *allfood* spell states, the hardness is dropped to 0 only for the sole purpose of eating the affected object (and not damaging the object in any other way) so the damage should affect the object's hit points directly, but what is that damage and how is it calculated?
- Can a creature with a bite natural attack use it to eat a weapon that is under the effects of *allfood* and have its bite damage bypass the hardness of the weapon, or would this be considered a sunder action that would still take the object's hardness into account?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95317/discussion-on-question-by-apathy-of-the-eggs-is-it-possible-to-eat-an-object-aff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This GM assumes that when a creature actually *finishes* eating an *entire* object, the consumer's dealt to that object enough damage to destroy that object. By extension, this GM would rule that a consumer that eats only *part* of an object removes a proportionate amount of hit points from that object. (This means that eating 1 lb. of 4-lb. longsword depletes of its 5 hp just 1 hp due to rounding.)

However, this GM would rule that a creature that wants to consume entirely or partially a typical [*allfood*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/allfood/)-affected object must usually take *several* rounds—[if not minutes](http://time.com/3853950/matt-stonie-five-pound-burrito-two-minutes/)—to consume that object, all the while provoking attacks of opportunity. Even dining gracelessly *on a longsword* is an act not to be rushed. In addition to the perils already present in chowing down on a pointy-and-razor-sharp murder implement, for example, that *allfood* Medium longsword *still* possesses 5 hit points, the same number of hp as a healthy [kobold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/kobold) and more than an angry but ill [human farmer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npc-0/bloodthirsty-farmer-cr-1-4/). (Because both kobold and farmer are far *bigger* than that longsword, maybe that *allfood* longsword is—even moreso than normal *allfood* material—almost *impossibly* chewy?) In other words, this may be a more daunting task than the ranger initially considered. Sitting down to a leisurely meal of *allfood* rocks or some slices of *allfood* splint mail? Sure. Take your time. Noshing on *allfood* arrows or an *allfood*  greatclub during a battle? Unwise… and probably a little rude.

(This assumes the *allfood*-affected object is noteworthy in its heft, size, or shape in comparison to the consumer; this GM would rule that a Medium average human consumer could gulp down an *allfood*-affected sized-appropriately-for-him sling stone or shuriken pretty quickly but that it may take even a famished Medium average human consumer at least several days to eat his way through an *allfood*-affected 50-lb. tree trunk!)

> #### "What about the mechanics?"
>
> Much to the despair of rules lawyers—among whom I sometimes count myself—*Pathfinder* doesn't mechanize *everything*, and, so far as I'm aware, one of the things without rules is the mundane task of just eating. If a GM really wants to extrapolate, examples and possible precedents exist, though. There's the [*heroes' feast*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heroes-feast/) spell that creates a magic spread that takes a creature an hour to consume. There's the extraordinary ability [swallow whole](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Swallow-Whole-Ex-), which isn't really eating *per se* but eventually can lead to digestion. There's taking a standard action that provokes attacks of opportunity to chug a [potion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions/) and even eat a [magic apple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/charm-bracelet/). And so on.
>
> But when a typical human-shaped adventurer retrieves a [hunk of cheese](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-gear/#TOC-Cheese) in the middle of battle then tries with his mouth to reduce that hunk of cheese's hp, this reader anthropomorphizes the game throwing up its hands and saying, "Really? I'm outta here. They're your players! You deal with them!"

Further, because the [*allfood*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/allfood/) spell's description says that an object affected by the spell "becomes no more vulnerable to sunder attacks, break attempts, or any other action typically directed against objects," this GM would rule that a creature's bite attack when its used to deal damage to the affected object during combat is still covered by the combat maneuver [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder) or [damaging objects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/), even if the creature doing the biting *plans* to consume the *allfood* affected object eventually. There is a difference between, for example, a [devil monkey](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/devil-monkey/) trying to snap with its teeth a foe's *allfood*-affected longsword and a devil monkey snacking on a banana or even—due to the [*prestidigitation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation) spell—a banana-flavored *allfood* longsword.

Comment: So it's still as hard as a sword, the only real difference is that you can digest it?  Man, what a weird spell.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil It *is* a weird spell. I mean, the *allfood* transformation is instantaneous so the object's forevermore changed, yet the transformed item doesn't *rot* because it's now food. I don't know what to *do* with that, but that's out there, as is, of course, adventurers just eating murder weapons or any other evidence of their wrongdoing.

Comment: The DM and I have, after much deliberation of magic, eating, and combat, decided that minutes of eating is justified in this scenario.  This obviously makes it not so worthwhile to do unless you're really trying to provoke an enemy.  Each pound takes half a minute to consume (5 turns).  If more than half the weight of the item is consumed, the item is no longer considered as a proper weapon and is treated as an improvised weapon for the rest of combat, though it takes no other penalties beyond that.  Obviously, if the item is completely consumed, then it's just gone.